# Boost spirit x3 parse into struct with skipping member if it empty

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I'm trying to figure out the way of parsing the following texts

```
function() {body ...}
function(args_) {body...}
```

Should i use the same struct for both variants or it could be done with only one struct

```
struct function
{
    std::string name_;
    std::vector<std::string> args_;
    statement_list body_;
};
```

The way i parse it for now (how to skip arguments if there is no arguments):

```
auto const identifier_def = raw[lexeme[(alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_')]];
auto const function_def  =
        lexeme["function" >> !(alnum | '_')] >> identifier
     >> '(' >> ((identifier % ',') )>> ')'
     >> '{' >> statement  >> '}'
        ;
```

And i could parse the variant with arguments, but not the one with no arguments!

I'm trying to use something like OR operator, but there was no success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As a quick hint, usually this works:

```
 >> '(' >> -(identifier % ',') >> ')'
```

Depending on the specific types (especially the declaration of `identifier`) you might have a tweak like this:

```
 >> '(' >> (-identifier % ',') >> ')'
```

An idea for forcing it:

```
 x3::rule<struct arglist_, std::vector<std::string> > { "arglist" }
         = '(' >> (
                       identifier % ','
                     | x3::attr(std::vector<std::string> ())
                   )
         >> ')';
```